# "new Thread" does not start a new thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, runnable

I want to start a new thread when the line with `new Thread` executes. I am doing it like this:

```
new Thread ( new Runnable() {

@Override
    public void run() {

            .....
    }
}).start();

//other code continues here
```

When the code comes to new thread line it jumps to execute other code. Why?

Comment: It will execute the code inside `run()` a bit later.

Comment: Because you're probably debugging the thread that is starting the new thread. If you put a logline or a breakpoint in the `run()` method, you'll see that it is executed

Comment: @0xDEADCODE I put a break point on the first line of code inside the run method... when I debug it still goes to other lines of code.

Comment: whichever answer helped you, you should mark it as correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well because the new thread almost immediately started running, and the code following the new thread declaration is being executed by the same previous thread.

This is what's happening:

```
// Main thread running

// Some random code...

new Thread ( new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    // This code will run in another thread. Usually as soon as start() gets called!
}
}).start();

// This code is still being executed by the main thread.
```

Other than attaching debugger, an easy way to check whether the thread really started running is to put a `Log` statement inside `run()`

Comment: How to check the executing code that runs in another thread "in-parallel" with the main thread ? I put a break point on first line of code inside the run() but it does not executed.

Comment: when did you put the breakpoint? before running your app or afterwards?

Comment: @Zobi do one thing, put a log in the run() method and check if it is being executed or not

Answer (score 1):

Simple: because exactly what you want to happen happens!

You create a new thread with **new()**, and because you call **start()** immediately on that object, that job starts doing **its** work.

And your main thread continues its "main" work. It is like: you clap your friend on his shoulder (to signal him: start running) - and now you are asking: "why is he gone?"

That is all there is to this!

Comment: So how I check the code executing inside run method ?

Comment: That depends on what this code is doing! We can't help with that part until you clarify what that code is supposed to do - and what you observe instead.

Comment: I want to login from android app than find files mounted on server and than download it

Comment: Again: we cant help you with debugging code that we can't see. In that sense: step back, and update your question. For example to include the core parts of what that thread is doing. Besides: the real answer is: do not put all that code into an anonymous inner class. Create a single class implementing that functionality. And then you can call that code on your main thread - just to see if it is working.